# Failed to build `dumpobj.ml` in repo `ocaml/tools/dumpobj.ml`

Tags: ocaml

I want to build the `dumpobj.ml` file in OCaml repo `ocaml/tools/dumpobj.ml`

by using

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg compiler-libs.common dumpobj.byte
```

but it failed

So I minimize the code to create a `test.ml`

```
let _ = Bytesections.Bad_magic_number;
```

still by using

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg compiler-libs.common test.byte
```

but the output is

```
ocamlfind ocamldep -package compiler-libs.common -modules test.ml > test.ml.depends
ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package compiler-libs.common -o test.cmo test.ml
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package compiler-libs.common test.cmo -o test.byte
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Required module `Bytesections' is unavailable
Exit code 2 while executing this command:
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package compiler-libs.common test.cmo -o test.byte
```

the OCaml version is 4.04

platform is Windows cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong ocamlfind package

```
➜  1 ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg compiler-libs.bytecomp a.byte
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package compiler-libs.bytecomp -o a.cmo a.ml
findlib: [WARNING] Interface topdirs.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/kakadu/.opam/4.04.0+flambda/lib/ocaml, /home/kakadu/.opam/4.04.0+flambda/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package compiler-libs.bytecomp a.cmo -o a.byte
findlib: [WARNING] Interface topdirs.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/kakadu/.opam/4.04.0+flambda/lib/ocaml, /home/kakadu/.opam/4.04.0+flambda/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
Finished, 3 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

Comment: `compiler-libs.bytecomp` works, but how do you know it's this package? Is there any list to get the package name?

Comment: run `ocamlfind list`